# Как создать многоуровневое меню?

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Подскажите как создать многоуровневое меню.В гугле искал, но что-то не работает.

Есть таблица `id | Name | parent_id`, где `parent_id` -это айди родителя.

Как пройтись циклом в PHP и вывести древовидный массив?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
 //Функция получения массива каталога
function get_cat() {
//запрос к базе данных
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result) {
    return NULL;
}
$arr_cat = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {

    //В цикле формируем массив
    for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result);$i++) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);

        //Формируем массив, где ключами являются адишники на родительские категории
        if(empty($arr_cat[$row['parent_id']])) {
            $arr_cat[$row['parent_id']] = array();
        }
        $arr_cat[$row['parent_id']][] = $row;
    }
    //возвращаем массив
    return $arr_cat;
}
}
?>



<?php
 //вывод каталога с помощью рекурсии
function view_cat($arr,$parent_id = 0) {

//Условия выхода из рекурсии
if(empty($arr[$parent_id])) {
    return;
}
echo '<ul>';
//перебираем в цикле массив и выводим на экран
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr[$parent_id]);$i++) {
    echo '<li><a href="?category_id='.$arr[$parent_id][$i]['id'].
                '&parent_id='.$parent_id.'">'
                .$arr[$parent_id][$i]['title'].'</a>';
    //рекурсия - проверяем нет ли дочерних категорий
    view_cat($arr,$arr[$parent_id][$i]['id']);
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';

}?>
```